# meaning of nextLine() method in scanner Class?

Tags: java

can anyone explain to me what exactly `nextLine` method mean in java ?
   how does it work ???
    and #why java skipped `nextLine()` if `nextInt()` method invoked before it as the    code below??!!

```
  int i;
  String s;
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  i=sc.nextInt(); //enter 5

  s=sc.nextLine(); // enter helloWorld
  System.out.println(i+"  **  "+s);
```

that will print

```
5  **
```

i have tried alot of code ... and i have tried to write `next()` method instead of `nextLine()` method ...and its work ...the problem just in `nextLine()` method

Comment: So... what's the issue? Do you want a link to documentation you should really learn to Google yourself? Do you want to [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and ask about an error?

Comment: It works as expected. It will read up to the next newline character

Comment: Text is simply collection of characters. We describe line as text between characters which are considered as line separators like `\r` `\n` like `"this is line 1\r\nthis is line 2"`. Problem with `nextInt` is that it doesn't *consume* these line separators, while `nextLine` tries to find characters *until* first line separators it will see (or until end of stream). So since `nextLine` didn't consume those `\r\n` `nextLine` finds them immediately, which means it returns *empty* String `""`.

Comment: nextLine() give you the rest of the line, after you called nextInt() you hit enter so nextLine() reads the rest of the line after the number you typed.

Comment: Oh, important thing is that when you are asking in console user for any data, user must press enter/return key to confirm its imput which is adding these line separators which cause this problem with `nextLine()`.